# Pagination shows same set of Data on all Pages

Tags: html, angularjs, pagination, controller

Im using pagination in angularJS to show search content which comes from API call.The problem being I get the same set of Data on all Pages.
Below is how Im trying.

**In Controller**

```
$rootScope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 5;

$scope.numberOfPages = function () {
    return Math.ceil($scope.GetsearchResults.length / $scope.pageSize);
}
```

**GetsearchResults is the Json Array: it is a then response**

*In Html Im using ng-repeat for li tag*

```html
     <li class="redirection clearfix" ng-repeat="result in GetsearchResults  | startFrom:currentPage * pageSize | limitTo:pageSize" ng-click="GetEditFormData(result.fromUrl,result.Markets);ShowEditRedirect($event);"> //some contents </li>

    <div class="pagination" ng-if="resultCount > 10"><button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage
    -1">Previous</button> {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}<button ng-disabled="currentPage >= GetsearchResults.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1"> Next </button></div>
```

**I have startFrom Filter in my controller like below**

```
app.filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (!input || !input.length) { return; }
        start = +start ; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

start variable in filter always gets value 0. I think currentPage is not getting incremented in ng-repeat.I do not understand why?

I refereed  this -> : http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `ng-if` inside your pagination menu you need to access the `$parent` scope like in this simple **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cn1t1jvL/)**. `ng-if` creates an isolated scope for it childs.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="redirection clearfix" ng-repeat="result in GetsearchResults  | startFrom:currentPage * pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">
      {{ result }}
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="pagination" ng-if="GetsearchResults.length > pageSize">
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" 
            ng-click="$parent.currentPage=$parent.currentPage-1">
      Previous
    </button> 
    {{currentPage+1}}/{{GetsearchResults.length / pageSize | ceil }}
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= GetsearchResults.length/pageSize - 1" 
            ng-click="$parent.currentPage=currentPage+1"> 
      Next 
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.currentPage = 0;
  $scope.pageSize = 5;
  $scope.GetsearchResults = [{
      id: 1
    }, {
      id: 5
    }, {
      id: 11
    }, {
      id: 31
    }, {
      id: 12
    }, {
      id: 3
    }, {
      id: 33
    }, {
      id: 34
    }, {
      id: 52
    }, {
      id: 103
    }, {
      id: 33
    }
  ];
});


/**
 * Start from filter
 */
myApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
  return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
  }
});

myApp.filter('ceil', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return Math.ceil(input);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **ng-show** instead of **ng-if** in the div.

```
 <div class="pagination" **ng-show**="resultCount > 10">
    <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage
        -1">Previous</button> {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
   <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= GetsearchResults.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1"> Next </button></div>
```